# Why does Microsoft word 2016 suggest unnecessary grammar fixes

Tags: microsoft-word

As you can see from the image below, Microsoft word 2016 makes some unnecessary suggestion for words like "really", "according to","that being said, you".

The third error for example, deletes most of the words, and only leaves the word "you".

I know how to turn this feature off, but I still want to figure out why it's happening, and see if it's an issue specifically with the 2016 version, since previous versions did not have this problem.

[image]

Comment: Those suggested grammar fixes are due to how the text is formatted and are actually valid grammar suggestions,  It also is worth pointing out, that Office 2017/Word 2017 does not actually exist, so please edit your question and provide the actual version of Word you are using.

Comment: Even the edit isn't any better grammatically. It's very 'conversational' & might work in a dialogue script, but not as formal writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically echoing Ramhound's comment above and agreeing with it: Microsoft Word is suggesting these grammar fixes because they are indeed errors in the grammar.

They might be the way you speak or write, or they may be relics of the formatting of the document (we don't often say "and point H is ..." so the document might have some formatting for comprehension that breaks the thoughts up in a way that makes correct grammar more awkward.

But the point remains, the highlighted sections in the document sample you have provided are indeed grammatically incorrect.

**The first one** is because the section starts off mid-sentence. "Or" is a conjunction, a combining word, that goes between clauses inside a single sentence. You do not begin a sentence with "or". While the highlight is on "really piss", the root of the problem is that you've structured this sentences, from the outset, incorrectly. You can begin the sentence with "accordingly" or another word that has a similar meaning but is appropriate for the beginning of a sentence.

**The second one** is because "according to" should never end a sentence. "According to" always requires a following "what": "According to this document", or "according to Benyamin", or something similar. "According to" needs an object to be complete.

**The third one** is because the comma is unnecessary to separate the clauses of the sentence.

Comment: I'm with you 99.9% of the way; though I'd lose "With" altogether in the Transition. "That being said," may be archaic & even cliché, but it can stand alone: it needs no "With" to kick it into gear. (I'm loath to comment on how I'd actually grade the paper as it stands ;)

Comment: Good point on the "with". "with" does seem to beg a preceding sentence, or merely duplicates the "that" which immediately follows it. (damn it, I'm a technologist, not a grammarian!)

Comment: I was going to comment on your use of "loath" instead of "loathe", but I googled it first, and you were right @Tetsujin.

Comment: I used it in that form, loath being 'reluctant' against loathe leaning heavily toward 'dislike', even 'hatred'... then double-checked. It would have been a poor place to make a mistake ;)

Comment: I should mention that these things happen either way, whether they're in the beginning of the sentence, middle, or end. Also that picture is edited, those sentence aren't complete in this picture. I just wanted to show the errors. I'll edit the screenshot to show you the whole thing.

Comment: The additional information really doesn't change anything, and we can't really get into the finer points of grammar because most of us are grammarian hobbyists at best, and not experts. But, Microsoft Word tends to have an aggressive and nonadjustable grammar engine. You should not take it's flags as rules, but as suggestions. But you should consider them to be generally informed suggestions. Microsoft doesn't hire dummies (or us hobbyists) to program their grammar engine. The succinct answer to your question remains: The flags are there because you are using incorrect grammar.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of your Office 365 subscription for continuing improvement! You seem to be asking for why this feature is provided. While your particular examples probably contain grammar errors, this "feature" can be aggressive and frequently makes me second guess styles of writing:

[image: as long as if]

"as long as" to "if"? Ok, it is conditional and saves a few words.

[[image: sufficient enough]]

"Sufficient" to "enough"? They seem the same to me. The few extra characters is not worth the time I took to second guess myself, seeing the red misspelled indicators, and Google to see if others are irritated by Microsoft's latest dynamic "features".

If you do not wish to pay for a subscription word processor (or other cloud applications) for the marginal increase in value, I may recommend buying an older, permanently licensed copy, or using Open Office (and preferably reporting bugs and/or contributing to fixes).

Sorry if my images are showing up as links, trying to build reputation through contributions and I must have at least 10 to use that feature of Markdown.

Comment: The features of Office 365 and a perpetual license of Office 2016 is exactly the same with regards to this feature (whatever feature you want to call the Grammar checker).  Specifically, at this time there is no unique grammar feature, limited to only Office 365.  For that reason alone, and the fact you are suggesting there is a unique grammar check Office 365 feature, i must downvote this answer.